# how to get values from var-source with linq

Tags: c#, linq, var

I have a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, Type> AllDrillTypes = new Dictionary<int, Type>()
{
  {13,typeof(TCHEMISTRY)},
  {14,typeof(TDRILLSPAN)}
};
```

where TCHEMISTRY and TDRILLSPAN are classes. Then I want to get rows from one of this classes like this:

```
Type T = AllDrillTypes[13];
var LC = Activator.CreateInstance( typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType( T ) );
MethodInfo M = T.GetMethod("FindAll", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new Type[] { }, null);    
LC = M.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
```

All this code works correctly. After that I need to get some rows like this:

```
var LingLC = from obj in LC where obj.RunID == 1001 select obj;
```

But this line causes error:

> "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'object'. 'Where' not found."

What's wrong with this code line?

Comment: Could you specify the type of error you are getting? This would help answering your question!

Comment: Are you sure you do want to use reflection in that way?

Comment: Error text is "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'object'. 'Where' not found."

Comment: If you're using reflection to create generic objects, how do you expect your *compiler* to know what type to resolve `obj` to? =)

Comment: When you call FindAll method on TChemistry class, what does it return? A collection? What is the type of collection? If it is List<TChemistry>, you will have to cast LC to List<TChemistry>, before you use Linq.

Comment: FindAll method return List<TChemistry>. How to cast LC to List<TChemistry>? User may select TChemistry or TDrillSpan.

Comment: You are setting Type T = AllDrillTypes[13], which is TChemistry. If it can be TDrillSpan, you need to cast FindAll result to List<T>. Also, MethodInfo.Invoke returns you an object, not List<TChemistry>

Comment: I tried this: LC = (List<T>)M.Invoke(null, new object[] { }); The error is "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: M.Invoke returns System.object so you can't query that that easy = }

Comment: Do TChemistry and TDrillSpan share a common interface that defines a RunId property?

Comment: No, TChemistry and TDrillSpan has independent (long) RunID property

Comment: check my answer. It should help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you can't change the class definitions, you can avoid using reflection:

```
// Getter dictionary rather than type dictionary.
Dictionary<int, Func<IEnumerable<object>>> DrillTypeGetters =
    new Dictionary<int, Func<IEnumerable<object>>>()   
    {  
        { 13, () => TCHEMISTRY.FindAll().Cast<object>() },
        { 14, () => TDRILLSPAN.FindAll().Cast<object>() }
    };
Dictionary<int, Func<object, int>> IDGetters =
    new Dictionary<int, Func<object, int>>()
    {
        { 13, o => ((TCHEMISTRY)o).RunID },
        { 14, o => ((TDRILLSPAN)o).RunID }
    };

IEnumerable<object> LC = DrillTypeGetters[13]();
IEnumerable<object> LingLC = 
    from obj in LC
    where IDGetters[13](obj) == 1001
    select obj;
```

Or you could even just switch on `13`/`14` and run a *completely different method* per type.

```
if (choice == 13)
    IEnumerable<TCHEMISTRY> LingLC =
        TCHEMISTRY.FindAll().Where(tc => tc.RunID == 1001);
else if (choice == 14)
    IEnumerable<TDRILLSPAN> LingLC =
        TDRILLSPAN.FindAll().Where(td => td.RunID == 1001);
```

Basically, if the two classes don't share any common hierarchy, you can't write any common code to deal with them. If they have lots of *similar* properties, you can use getters as in my first example to provide a way to get the similar properties whatever type of class you're dealing with. If they don't even have similar properties, don't try to write shared code.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't to change declaration of classes. T

Comment: Hah OK. Still you should be able to do half of this without reflection, let me see.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could rewrite your code to something like this, .... to get a more type-safe solution (without using reflection).

```
void Main()
{
    var driller1 = new DrillerWhichYouCannotChange1();
    var driller2 = new DrillerWhichYouCannotChange2();

    var allDrillTypes = new Dictionary<int, IList<IDriller>>()
    {
        { 13, new List<IDriller>() { new DrillerWhichYouCannotChange1Adapter(driller1) } },
        { 14, new List<IDriller>() { new DrillerWhichYouCannotChange2Adapter(driller2) } },
    };

    Console.WriteLine(allDrillTypes[13][0].SomeCommonProperty); // prints 123
    Console.WriteLine(allDrillTypes[14][0].SomeCommonProperty); // prints 456
}

interface IDriller
{
    int SomeCommonProperty { get; }
}

class DrillerWhichYouCannotChange1Adapter : IDriller
{
    private DrillerWhichYouCannotChange1 inner;

    public DrillerWhichYouCannotChange1Adapter(DrillerWhichYouCannotChange1 inner)
    {
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    public int SomeCommonProperty { get { return this.inner.PropertyX; } }
}

class DrillerWhichYouCannotChange2Adapter : IDriller
{
    private DrillerWhichYouCannotChange2 inner;

    public DrillerWhichYouCannotChange2Adapter(DrillerWhichYouCannotChange2 inner)
    {
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    public int SomeCommonProperty { get { return this.inner.PropertyY; } }
}

class DrillerWhichYouCannotChange1
{
    public int PropertyX { get { return 123; } }
}

class DrillerWhichYouCannotChange2
{
    public int PropertyY { get { return 456; } }
}
```

**EDIT**: If you cannot change the driller classes, you could use the adapter-pattern to create one adapter per driller, which implements `IDiller`.

Comment: It's good approach, but in my case classes Driller1 and Driller2 are created automatically, so I can't change them declaration

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast LC to the to the return type of the FindAll method. Something on the lines of:

```
var genericList = ((List<TChemistry>) LC);
var LingLC = from obj in genericList where obj.RunID == 1001 select obj;
```

This is assuming that FindAll returns a collection of TChemistry.

--edit

If you do not know at runtime if the type will be TChemistry or TDrillspan, then you will have to write an if/else of switch statement to cast to the correct type. I would rather have TChemistry and TDrillSpan extend an abstract class or an interface, and you can just cast to List, and you will always have RunId property.

```
public abstract class TAbstract
{
   public abstract int RunId {get; set;}
}

public class TChemistry : TAbstract
{
    public override int RunId {get; set;}
}

public class TDrillSpan : TAbstract
{
   public override int RunId {get; set;}
}

Type T = AllDrillTypes[13] as TAbstract;
var LC = Activator.CreateInstance( typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType( T ) );
MethodInfo M = T.GetMethod("FindAll", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new Type[] { }, null);    
LC = M.Invoke(null, new object[] { });

var genericList = ((List<TAbstract>) LC);
var LingLC = from obj in genericList where obj.RunID == 1001 select obj;
```

If you cannot change the declaration of classes, then you are only left with ugly if else:

```
var typeInfo = LC.GetType();
IEnumerable<T> genericList;
if (typeInfo == typeof(IEnumerable<TChemistry>)
{
    genericList = (List<TChemistry>) LC;
)
else if (typeInfo == typeof(IEnumerable<TDrillSpan>)
{
    genericList = (List<TDrillSpan>) LC;
}

var LingLC = from obj in genericList where obj.RunID == 1001 select obj;
```

Comment: You'll need to do the cast to a new variable of type `List<TChemistry>` - casting and storing it back in an `object` won't help.

Comment: True.. I need that morning coffee!

Comment: This is good solution, but I can't change declaration of classes

Answer (score 0):

try

```
IEnumerable returnedObjects = (IEnumerable)M.Invoke(null, new object[] { }) as IEnumerable;
```

then iterate through your ienumerable

```
foreach (object report in returnedObjects)
{
    // Use reflection to read properties or add to a new List<object> if you
    // need an ICollection<object>
}
```

instead of :

```
LC = M.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
```

Comment: I think it works, but too much code lines. Thank you. I will try use it and than I will answer

Comment: as you wish my friend, as you wish =)

Comment: this code does't work, error text is "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumeartor'"